# How do I run this SQL Server query to group by department

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I want to achieve this result

| Department | Status In | Count | Status Out | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IT | In | 34 | Out | 34 |
| F&B | In | 100 | Out | 100 |
| House Keeping | In | 150 | Out | 150 |

but for now I get multiple departments from my query

[image]

Comment: How is the value `100` computed for the `F&B` department?

Comment: Please that is just an example the values in the table are just an example the correct value’s are those in the image thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want one row per department, remove status from the GROUP BY clause and use conditional aggregation. That involves using a case expression (or similar) in the COUNT aggregate.

```
select Department, 
      'In' as [Status In], 
       count(case Status when 'In' then 1 end) as [Count In], 
      'Out' as [Status Out], 
       count(case Status when 'Out' then 1 end) as [Count Out] 
 from dbo.V_Clean_Data
where Status in ('In', 'Out')
group by Department 
order by Department;
```

It is a bad habit to attempt to use the same name for multiple columns. Many tools will not support that. Don't know why you include the actual status values in each row since that is quite redundant.

I added some best practices. Schema-qualify your table names. Order of rows usually matters and that is only guaranteed by an ORDER BY clause. Use statement terminators.

Comment: thanks SMor that was simple and nice.